# How to click on a button, which is located at position 2 in ListView via robotium automation?

Tags: android, robotium

I want to automate a scenario, like click on a button, which is located at position 2 in ListView.
PFB code it automatically click a button at index 1 in ListView

```
TextView a = (TextView)solo.getView(R.id.dialog);
solo.clickOnView(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

U have a particular id for that button . set the tag by `setTag()` for that button then set the on click event:: like

```
 getView((int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
          LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
             // use inflater and do all those normal things..
    }
   view.setTag(position);
   myButton.setTag(view.getTag());          
   myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
           Toast.makeText(getContext()," Slot Button clicked " +  v.getTag(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: I want for Robotium Automation

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use **performClick()** method on the ListViews item like that:

```
   ((Button)((View) listView.get(1)).findViewById(R.id.mybutton)).performClick();
```

if you want just make itemClick, you should use **onItemCkick()** of the **ListView**

Comment: Thanks for that. Actually, I am asking for Robotium automation.